# Difference in using LSTM for fixed sized input and variable size input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I wonder how I can train (natural) LSTM model where I just feed a single time step one by one in one loop using all data points, and not just of a sample with a fixed time lenght of history data points.

And, what might be the difference and why is it standard to use a fixed lenght whereas the using all point step by step is the more  intuitive way?

Beside my theoretical question, is there an good example using a loop for single time steps instead of feeding the whole window to a LSTM?

Answer (score 0):

Both PyTorch and TensorFlow implementations of RNNs are done using tensors as inputs, which are processed with vector operations in the CPU or the GPU). This requires for the full input tensor to be present in memory.

However, you could implement your own RNN with a model that is a single block, and run it inside a for loop which inserts the output of the previous iteration as input to the model, alongside the regular input of the current iteration.

csirmaz made a similar thing which you can use as a reference: https://github.com/csirmaz/superloop.

Comment: Hey, I think maybe we missed each other. I suppose I am interested in normal training and usage things.  Like here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention?hl=en#training

Comment: Ther3 you also use for loop for training, Compare to here for pytorch: https://blog.floydhub.com/gru-with-pytorch/

Comment: Then, I asked myself above question. As the theoretical apporocasch is also aloop for very SINGLE Time step, right? I I use a historiy of 1 I am able to train variable lenght models, wheres I also can train models with fixed history size....

Comment: In PT and TF the model shape needs to be fixed for it to train, which means a fixed input size. The usual workaround is padding inputs with non-fixed length.