# RNN Step for Step, Cell vs Layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

How to implement RNN model time step for step like from the intuitive pictures shown to symbolize RNNs.

Do I need RNNCells? Whats the difference between a cell and using rnn layer with one single time step input?

Comment: Please read the docs

Comment: As mentioned in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/SimpleRNNCell) of `tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNNCell` : *This class processes one step within the whole time sequence input, whereas tf.keras.layer.SimpleRNN processes the whole sequence.*

Comment: So I would need a for loop for all time steps? Do you have an example maybe? Because I am confused: When is training stopped as no fixed time history is needed? So you do not need to create window batch samples with fixed window. Do I feed all data points in this loop?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67461949/difference-in-using-lstm-for-fixed-sized-input-and-variable-size-input